# Trying to install Pod but getting an error

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMGdl.png)I want to use google map for my application. By the guidence of google map SDK for iOS. I am installing pod but getting an error.
That is something like below.

The dependency `GoogleMaps` is not used in any concrete target.

Comment: Could you please show your pod.?

Comment: i have attached image

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify a target for each pod.

e.g. if before you had your Podfile written like this:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

just change it to

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target "TargetName" do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Comment: change the target name as of yours.

Comment: have you seen i have attached screenshot here. actually asking question for the first time here

Comment: installing GoogleMaps (1.13.2)

Comment: bro how to add textfields over GMSMapView